# How to copy data from one row into another, in the same table? 

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to copy data from specific columns in one row, and have it inserted/updated into another row, all in the same table.  Each row already has an ID # (called order_no), so no auto-increment is needed.

I thought this would be pretty simple, but it's just not working. my Table name is 'orders' and the columns are called 'rn' and 'phone' and the order_no are '416' and '417'. I want rn, and phone from 416 to be inserted into the rn, and phone columns for 417.

I also have tried this query, attempting to copy just one record rn, with no success
and get **error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE orders
  SET rn =
     ( SELECT rn
        FROM ( SELECT rn
                FROM orders
                  WHERE order_no = 416
             ) 
 WHERE order_no = 417 ");
```

I have tried this with no success, and get **Error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

```
  mysql_query
(" INSERT INTO orders (rn, phone)
SELECT rn, phone, 416
from orders
WHERE order_no = 417 ");
```

**Update.** I also tried this query below, with just one field (rn) to no avail, and it throws error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause:

```
     mysql_query("UPDATE orders 
SET rn = (SELECT rn FROM orders WHERE order_no = '416') 
WHERE order_no = '417' ");
```

Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you get an error? What happened?

Comment: The error I get, using the updated query is: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your query

```
mysql_query
(" INSERT INTO orders (rn, phone)
SELECT rn, phone, 416
WHERE order_no = 417 ");
```

to

```
mysql_query
(" INSERT INTO orders (rn, phone)
SELECT rn, phone, 416
from orders
WHERE order_no = 417 ");
```

Comment: The above query gives me this error: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: You are inserting TWO values but in select part you specify THREE values - of course it doesn't match the value count, it's really not difficult to spot and fix.

Comment: I thought the 416 specified the id where the rn, and phone data comes from. Where would I specify where to select them from? Does it need a sub-query like my second attempt up top?

Comment: Tried this also, with just one field (rn) to no avail, and it gives error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause:        mysql_query("UPDATE orders
SET rn = (SELECT rn FROM orders WHERE order_no = '416') 
WHERE order_no = '417' ");

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the right way... try this

```
INSERT INTO orders  (rs, phone)
SELECT rs, phone
from orders
WHERE id = 416
```

it will create your id #417

Comment: I already have ID #417, and would like to move/copy just two specific fields into it from 416 (same column field names rn, phone)

Comment: I have set rows, that are updated using a CRUD (minus the delete). They just over write the data, and no additional rows (ID's) are ever created. 416 acts as a pending row, and when ready a user clicks a button and the query would be executed to move the data to 417....still no luck getting this to work. Update query used above does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same table in update and value statement, because it can lead to infinite loops. You should use temporary tables like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tb_name(SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE where_case);
UPDATE original_table SET field_name = (SELECT field_name FROM temp_tb_name WHERE where_case) WHERE where_case;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tb_name
```

If you forgot to drop temporary table it will be dropped automatically when db_connection will be broken